# What can i do to insert file name with a single quotes from excel to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import, include

What can i do to insert file name with a single quotes from excel to mysql?
if I put the name without quotation, like this:

> Andi

its working out, but if I put the name without quotation ( ' ), like this:

> And'i

it didnt work.
Please Help :(

Comment: So how are you trying to import from Excel to MySQL? What library are you using? or is this loading from a CSV? Unless you tell us **how** you're trying to do the import, we can't do much to help fix your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to escape quotation character with a `\ (backslash)` character.

see here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html

also here for php: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Is it like this script `$pattern = preg_replace("/\'/","",$pattern);`  ??

Comment: not exactly. we are not trying to destroy the character. we are just trying to `escape` it. you can easily write `$myEscapedString = mysql_real_escape_string($myPlainString);`. it's very easy. you don't need to worry about which characters to escape. PHP does that for you.

Comment: p.s: if you don't want to use mysql specific funciton, i advice `preg_quote()` instead of `preg_replace()`.

Comment: yes its working out, im using `mysql_real_escape_string` like what u said. Thx u so much :)